# Insert data in parent table after INSERT conflicted FK_constraint SQLException Error 547

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlexception

I made an app in Java where I can view and modify my MS SQL tables.

```
public static void insertParts(String tableName, Vector<String> colNames, Vector<Object> data) throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (");
    for (int j = 0; j < colNames.size(); j++) {
        query.append(colNames.get(j));
        if (j != (colNames.size() - 1)) {
            query.append(", ");
        } else {
            query.append(") VALUES(");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < colNames.size(); i++) {
        query.append("?");
        if (i != (colNames.size() - 1)) {
            query.append(", ");
        } else {
            query.append(")");
        }
    }
    stmt = ccd_db_connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query.toString());
    for (int j = 0; j < colNames.size(); j++) {
        stmt.setObject(j + 1, data.get(j));
    }
    stmt.execute();
    stmt.close();
}
```

It works like charm when I use it for parent tables or a relational table where the foreign keys already exist of course.

If a parent record doesnt exist I get the following exception as expected:

> SQL STATE: 23000 ERROR CODE: 547 MESSAGE:INSERT statement conflicted
>   with COLUMN FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Something'. The conflict
>   occurred in database 'dbY', table 'TableX', column 'ColumnZ'.

I want a way so when this happens ( I guess on the try catch part), the user should get prompted if he wants to add the parent data, taking him directly to the parent table or cancel the whole insertion.

Since the insertion is dynamic is there any way to get the reference of the parent table?

So far only the String Message seems to give me that info but Ι guess its a bit of a makeshift rather a stable solution.

Any suggestion would be really helpful because I got stuck at this point.